# Append to dict inside a list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have the following structure(s) that I need to merge into a single list of dicts.

I can change the syntax/structure of the `secrets` list (into something else if easier).

```
vars:
  users:
    - name: foo
      database: foodb
    - name: bar
      database: bardb

  secrets:
    - name: foo
      password: foopass
    - name: bar
      password: barpass
```

Expected result:

```
users:
  - name: foo
    database: foodb
    password: foopass
  - name: bar
    database: bardb
    password: barpass
```

I have tried several filters to no avail, the closest I've come is this:

```
tasks: 
  - set_fact: foo: "{{ foo|default([]) + [item | combine(secrets, recursive=True)] }}"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Result:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got u'foo'"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    users:
      - name: foo
        database: foodb
      - name: bar
        database: bardb
    secrets:
      - name: foo
        password: foopass
      - name: bar
        password: barpass
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tmp_user: "{{ item | combine(secrets | selectattr('name','equalto',item.name) | first) }}"
      with_items: "{{ users }}"
      register: tmp_users
    - set_fact:
        users: "{{ tmp_users.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_user') | list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: Excellent! Works as it should :-)